# Create variables dynamically in loop JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am retrieving a HashMap from a servlet request with some arrays, their names would be Items1, Items2, ItemsN. I'll never know the HashMap size exactly, so I want to create variables with `<c:set/>` tag iterating a `<c:forEach/>` loop because I don't want to create them manually like this:

```
<c:set var="listItems1" value="${Map['Items1']}" scope="session"/>
<c:set var="listItems2" value="${Map['Items2']}" scope="session"/>
<c:set var="listItems3" value="${Map['Items3']}" scope="session"/>
<c:set var="listItems4" value="${Map['Items4']}" scope="session"/>
<c:set var="listItems5" value="${Map['Items5']}" scope="session"/>
```

Instead of that I want to create them in this way:

```
<c:forEach items="${Map['Items']}" var="Items" varStatus="i">
     <c:set var="${listItems + i.index}" value="${Items}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

But I can't because JSTL tells me

> According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute var does not accept any expressions

Then, I was wondering if is it possible create variables dynamically in JSTL or I have to create them manually

Comment: understand the purpose of `forEach` _it iterates over a collection of objects_ . why do you want the create the variables from the loop ? and what is their purpose ?

Comment: Thanks for asking, above I am creating 5 variables manually because I'm assuming the size of ${Map['Items']} never will exceed 5 items, in most of cases some of this variables will be empty because the size is less than 5 items, but in the case ${Map['Items']} exceeds 5 items I will have to add more variables manually, then I want to avoid this creating them dynamically. If is there any better solution...

Comment: It could be useful, but not for this question, that loop is the same I'm using in my question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll never know the HashMap size exactly.

You can use jstl function length, to get length of hashmap as:

```
    Length of Map : ${fn:length(yourMap)}
```

Make sure to include this in jsp: <%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>

If you need to iterate based on size of hashmap and do something, you can try as:

```
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${yourMap.size()}">
       //do something
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and it's valid, but the issue is not how to iterate the HashMap, the issue is create the variable dynamically inside "var" atributte of <c:set/> tag while I am iterating through HashMap.

Comment: @user2573318 You cannot have a dynamic value for var literal in c set.