# Java JSP forEach load more with AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm using JSP, JSTL, Servlets, jQuery, Hibernate, MySQL.
I'm a noob at ajax.

Here's the piece of code I'm dealing with:

```
<c:forEach var="recipe" items="${recipes}" end="9">

  content goes here

</c:forEach>
```

I wonder if it's possible to change the `end="9"` with AJAX. Or perhaps there's a better solution to this.
Data comes from a DB via hibernate and selected with JPQL.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750250/create-variables-dynamically-in-loop-jstl

Comment: My question and that question are completely different.